# Get all the commits part of the release with Github API

Tags: javascript, python, github, github-api

Is there a way to get the details about all the files changed and who changed them associated with a release . I checked the github release api and it does not give the details about the files changed. If the api could give the details about the commits that would be good to.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/

Answer (score 0):

The Commit GitHub API allows you to:

- [list commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository)
- compare [any two commits (or branches)](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)

So for each commit from the first step, you would need to :

- [either get each commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), which includes a `diff_url` field nad a `patch_url` field,
- or (faster) directly query that diff URL that you can deduce from the list of commits returned by the step one.

  ```
  https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/commit/<commit>.diff
  ```